# ggplot2: creating line graphs with clipping off and anchored at y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to create a line graph where the line either starts at the edge of the y axis or is ongoing from an unseen data point (i.e., in the following code, the datapoint for 2010 is set outside the xlim parameters. I don't want 2010 to appear on the x axis). It works until I try to lay the horizontal y axis labels over the top. Clip off allows me to add the labels, but I can't find a way to then start the line graph from the edge of the y axis without running over the page.

```
data <- data.frame(Decade = c(2010, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, 2060),
                   Percent = c(0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75))

p <-ggplot(data, aes(x = Decade, y = Percent, group =1), lwd = 1.5) +
  geom_line(linetype=2) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1), xlim=c(2020,2060)) +scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+labs(title="Title", x ="Decade", y = "Percent %") +
  geom_point()

p2 <- p + coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(0, 1)) +
  theme( # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
    # explicitly set the horizontal lines (or they will disappear too)
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="grey" ), 
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line( size=.1, color="grey" ), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=15), 
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=15, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 60, b = 0, l = 0)), 
    plot.title = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"))

p2 + ggplot2::annotate("text", x = 2010, y = 1.04, label = "Complete Inclusion", hjust =1.3, size =3.2, fontface = "italic") +
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = 2010, y = .04, label = "Complete Exclusion", hjust = 1.25, size =3.2, fontface = "italic")
```

[image]
I'd like to recreate the image attached, but with the horizontal y axis labels from the code above added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `annotate` one option to fix your issue would be to add your annotations via the axis text. To this end I pass a custom function to the `labels=` argument where I add the annotations to the top and bottom label. For the italic font face I use `ggtext::element_markdown`. Another advantage of this approach is that it does not require to make room for the annotations via the axis title margin. Depending on your desired result still some fiddling is required to "shift" the top and bottom labels so that the numbers still align with the ticks:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Decade, y = Percent, group = 1), lwd = 1.5) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), xlim = c(2020, 2060)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1, .25),
    labels = \(x) {
      labels <- scales::percent(x)
      labels[1] <- paste0(
        "*Complete Exclusion*<br>",
        labels[1]
      )
      labels[length(labels)] <- paste0(
        "*Complete Inclusion*<br>",
        labels[length(labels)]
      )

      labels
    }
  ) +
  labs(title = "Title", x = "Decade", y = "Percent %") +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(
      vjust = c(.3, rep(.5, 3), .3)
    )
  )

p +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .1, color = "grey"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(size = .1, color = "grey"),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold")
  )
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
```

[image]